# trigger to auto-populate the Sales target name field based on the User (lookup Field)

Tags: apex, trigger, lookup, before-trigger

I just start in APEX and I have been trying to develop a trigger which isnt working, The requirement is that

I have a **Sales Target Name** field that should auto-populate in a form when I associate a Salesman (which is a lookup field on a User) once Salesman is fullfill in the form and we click save the trigger should autopopulate the **Sales Target Name** with the User Alias associate to the Salesman fill in the form

**the trigger is**

```
trigger populateSTName on Sales_Target__c (before insert , before update){ 
    Set<Id> setConIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Sales_Target__c obj : trigger.new) {
        if (obj.Name != null) {
            setConIds.add(obj.Name);
        }
    }
    Map<Id, User> mapCon = new Map<Id, User>([Select Id, Alias from User where id in: setConIds]);
    for (Sales_Target__c obj : trigger.new) {
        if (obj.Name != null) {
            if (mapCon.containsKey(obj.Name)) {
                User c = mapCon.get(obj.Name);
                obj.Name = c.Alias;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**THE FORM**
[image]

Is there someone who can help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Could you please [edit] your post to describe the behavior you are currently seeing, or any error messages you receive or view in your debug logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be out of luck on this one.

Semantic errors aside (I think that `if (obj.Name != null)` should be `if (obj.Salesman__c != null)`, with similar replacements for all other instances of `obj.Name` except for `obj.Name = c.Alias;`), you're running into a system validation rule.

The standard `Name` field is always required (for the objects that have a Name field).

When you push the "Save" button, Salesforce goes through a specific [order of execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm).

System validation is the second execution step, whereas your before trigger (any before triggers) are the fourth. So Salesforce is stopping you before you even get into your before trigger.

There may be a chance that you could get away with this if you were using a Visualforce page or a Lighting Web Component (LWC for short), but if you're using the standard UI record creation page then I don't believe you can escape system validation.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot it works ! Thank you so much to have take the time to answer me